# Ansible list single/double quotes

Tags: ansible, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have created a list which I want to use as input parameter into the body of the `uri` module. When I try to use the list I face an issue with single/double quoting.

```
- set_fact:
        my_entities: "{{ entities.results | json_query('[].json.entities[].entityId') }}"



TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************

ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"my_entities": ["HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0", "HOST-41B005A2056B6C03"]}, "changed": false}
```

```yaml
    - name: test 
      uri:
         url: "XXXXX"
         method: POST
         headers:
            Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
            Authorization: XXXXX
         return_content: yes  
         status_code: 201
         body: "{\"metadata\":{\"clusterVersion\":\"Mock version\"},\"scope\":{\"entities\":[\"{{ my_entities }}\"]}}
         validate_certs: no
         body_format: json
```

When I run the playbook I can see in the failure report that the entities are listed single quoted.

```json
"scope": {
          "entities": [
            "['HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0', 'HOST-41B005A2056B6C03']"
          ],
```

When I only select the first value from the list, it works:

```yaml
body: "{\"metadata\":{\"clusterVersion\":\"Mock version\"},\"scope\":{\"entities\":[\"{{ my_entities | first }}\"]}}
```

In the report I can see that the entities is like:

```json
 "entities": [
            "HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0"
          ],
```

In conclusion, I want to use the complete list `{{ my_entities }}` into the `uri` POST call where the entities should get populated as `["HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0", "HOST-41B005A2056B6C03"]`

Comment: "['HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0', 'HOST-41B005A2056B6C03']"  is a string not a list...or its error typo?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @Frenchy its not a typo error. This is copy pasted from the playbook execution. When i run my playbook with the ansible_facts: "my_entities" i can see in the failed task json output that entities is populated as: "['HOST-CD2D2A58FB173BF0', 'HOST-41B005A2056B6C03']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dunno if you want list or list of list....

try this:

```
body: '{"metadata":{"clusterVersion":"Mock version"},"scope":{"entities":[{{my_entities}}] } }'
```

or this:

```
body: '{"metadata":{"clusterVersion":"Mock version"},"scope":{"entities":{{my_entities}} } }'
```

Comment: The issue was with the Double [] brackets. So when removing those like in your 2nd answer did the trick!